# react-navigation v4 TypeError: (0, _core.createNavigator) is not a function

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to run a project with version 0.63.3 and these dependencies:

```
 "react-navigation": "^4.4.3",
 "react-navigation-drawer": "^1.4.0",
 "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^1.1.1",
 "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
 "react-navigation-tabs": "^1.2.0",
```

I keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: (0, _core.createNavigator) is not a function. (In '(0, _core.createNavigator)(NavigationView, router, config)', '(0, _core.createNavigator)' is undefined)
```

I believe it is something about the versions but I cant find how to solve it. Unfortunately it is not possible to update the project right now. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code of the Tab in react-navigation4:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Home!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: HomeScreen,
  Settings: SettingsScreen,
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

You can find anything related to the version4 [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/tab-based-navigation)

Later on, You can update it to navigation version 6.